# Print node body removing html entities?

Tags: theming

Im printing the node body in my tpl file with this:

```
 <?php print render(field_view_field("node", $node, "body", array(
  "label"=>"hidden",
  "type" => "text_summary_or_trimmed",
  "settings"=>array("trim_length" => 150),
))); ?>
```

The " and ' characters in the node's content are breaking the page as im putting this in a mailto link. How can I make sure these characters are printed as non html entities eg `&#34;` instead of ".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could wrap it in PHP's [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) and [strip_tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) functions:

```
$body_trimmed = render(field_view_field("node", $node, "body", array(
  "label"=>"hidden",
  "type" => "text_summary_or_trimmed",
  "settings"=>array("trim_length" => 150),
))); 
print htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($body_trimmed));
```

This would give you plain text with special characters encoded.

Alternately, if all you want to do is escape the quote characters and leave the divs in place, you could do a search/replace using [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) for each, adding the backslash to escape them:

```
$body_trimmed = render(field_view_field("node", $node, "body", array(
  "label"=>"hidden",
  "type" => "text_summary_or_trimmed",
  "settings"=>array("trim_length" => 150),
))); 
$body_trimmed = str_replace("'","\'",$body_trimmed);
$body_trimmed = str_replace('"','\"',$body_trimmed);
print $body_trimmed;
```

Comment: That outputs all the divs as plain text.

Comment: How do you want the divs to render if you are using this in a mailto link? Can you give an example of how you are using it?

Comment: As its going to be in the body of an email I want plain text. I need to escape the ' and " characters as they break the link.

Comment: See if the edits above help in your situation.

Comment: Great's is converted to Great\'s. So the ' character is still breaking the link.

Comment: In addition to this, I need the character that the ' and " get converted to to be readable when in the email's body.

Comment: This site achieves what I need to: http://time.com/3524384/ebola-thomas-eric-duncan-contacts-containment/

Comment: Did you try the revised first option above? Give me a before/after example (what you have and what you want it to end up like) and I will see if I can revise again to achieve it.

Comment: Yes I tried your latest code. Before I had Great's which is not converted to Great\'s. What I need is Great&#39;s

Comment: If you leave aside the "Alternately" section of my answer, the first part was also revised. Did you try that with the "strip_tags" function included?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18015/discussion-between-laryn-and-jdln).

Comment: Sorry I was using the 2nd code. Its working now with the first load. Thanks a lot